# splitting areas onto different monitors

Tags: workflow

I would like to either split an area and move onto another monitor so they remain in sync or open a new Blender window (instance) move it to another monitor and sync both.

Is that possible and how to do it?

Comment: I remember this being possible...

Answer (score 1):

Click on the window button a the the top of the screen.
[image: window button]

Then click on new window (or new main window if thats what you want).
[image: new window button]

That should work hopfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> drag on any area corner to open a copy of it in a new window. You can then do whatever you want with that window.
You can do the same using the menu `View` ‣ `Area` ‣ `Duplicate Area into new window`.

[Areas — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/areas.html)

You can also open a new window using the menu `Window` ‣ `New Window`.

[Topbar — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/topbar.html#window-menu)